# BIM 360 fail to translate downloaded file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I'm uploading rvt files to BIM 360 DOCS using forge BIM360 API
Both requests to upload file and to assign file version are returning success,
Nontheless when I go to BIM360 docs I'm not able to visualize files in the viewer, the files are failing at the conversion to svf:

```
  "messages": [
    {
      "type": "error",
      "message": "Possibly recoverable warning exit code from extractor: -536870935",
      "code": "TranslationWorker-RecoverableInternalFailure"
    },
    {
      "type": "error",
      "code": "Revit-UnsupportedFileType",
      "message": "<message>The file is not a Revit file or is not a supported version.
```

The same file works fine when I upload it manually.

```
        Uri baseUrl = new Uri("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/" +objectId);
        IRestClient client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
        IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(baseUrl, Method.PUT);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/octet-stream");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", token);
        request.AddFile(fileName, filePath);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Althought it returns Success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I supose that the error must somewhere in my upload request:

Comment: yes, it can happen when your code does not upload file completely, or with wrong content type, or with additional data. Normally, after uploading, compare the returned SHA1 with the original file SHA1 if they are same. This is a sample of uploading object in .NET which might help you to address the issue at your side: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-viewhubs/blob/master/forgeSample/Controllers/DataManagementController.cs#L315

Comment: yes, that was the problem, I've replaced Restsharp by the framework and it worked fine. I think that something in the method AddFile() from restsharp library is corrupting the file while uploading it.